# Extent image in libvips with white background

Tags: vips

I want to extent the image using vips. In PHP imagick it has method `Imagick::extentImage`. How can I achieve it with vips. I found this link but it's not giving output as I want

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/857

How can I pass x and y coordinates like imagick.

```
extentImage( $width, $height, $x, $y )
```

Comment: You need `$new = $old->embed($x, $y, $width, $height, ["extend" => "white"]);`, see https://libvips.github.io/php-vips/docs/classes/Jcupitt-Vips-ImageAutodoc.html#method_embed

Comment: There's also `gravity` if your x/y is something simple, for example: `$new = $old->gravity("north", $width, $height, ["extend" => "white"]);` will place `$old` top centre.